Does all the existence have a will to remain existing?
First of all: i am a layman.
Body/bodies: Material Being/Has mass and volume
And what i mean by the title: Everything that exists (that is composed by any chemical element) has the will/determination to keep existing as long as it can. Everything that a body does is for the sake of its survival; all existent bodies requires energy to keep its existence, and they go after get that energy in order to keep it.
So, is there some kind of law that keeps these bodies with the will of keeping their existence. That forms all bodies with a purpose of keep their existence?
I'm not talking about a conscious will, obviously. More as a law of nature.
(I'm using Reverso Text, so any grammar mistakes please let me know.)

"Everything that exists has the will"??? Also stones? In what sense?

Well, I imagine there’s a reason the stones don’t crumble at any moment. Maybe something to do with the atoms that stay condensed.

Corpses are doing a lousy job of survival, being dead, and of existence, decaying into dust. The law must be doing a lousy job of keeping up their will.

corpse is a dead body, perhaps you mean something else? is this a joke or what?

Sorry, i'm using Reverso Text. Gonna fix that.


Does all the existence have a will to remain existing?
And what i mean by the title: Everything that exists (that is composed by any chemical element) has the will/determination to keep existing as long as it can. Everything that a body does is for the sake of its survival; all existent bodies requires energy to keep its existence, and they go after get that energy in order to keep it.

radioactive decay seems to be a counterexample

So, is there some kind of law that keeps these bodies with the will of keeping their existence. [?] That forms all bodies with a purpose of keep their existence?
I'm not talking about a conscious will, obviously. More as a law of nature.

if anything, the second law of the thermodynamics may be regarded somewhat to point to the opposite conclusion

Maybe the atoms that radioactively decay are holding on "as long as they can." Many systems that persist over time have some "restorative force" or process that tends to resist damaging changes to some extent. A rock has molecular bonds holding it together, for example, that push back against external attempts to break the rock.

2nd law of thermodynamics defines an arrow of time. The fact that certain processes like the removal of a divider in a two phase gas, produces a more symmetric one-phase gas, has nothing to with life/death (although a common belief). Obviously evolution is not contrary to 2nd law of thermodynamics
